Sorting a string before a number with Postgres and Django
I want to use fuzzy dates for sorting a Django query, so you can use a full date if you have it, but maybe you only know year and month or maybe you only know year or even decade. For example, Jan XX 2024 would come before Jan 1 2024 and Jan 2 2024. I was originally planning to store as a string 202401XX, 20240101, etc, but Postgres naturally sorts characters after numbers so this would put the date with no day AFTER the date with day specified.
I was thinking of converting the 20240101 to letters before saving to the database (X=A, 0=F, 1=G, etc) since this is a computationally cheap thing and I could control where everything sorted. Is this a terrible idea? Is there a better way? I don't want to do a custom Postgres query because that would be complicated with Django's built-in pagination.
This is for storing old family photos - everything from modern digital cameras with full time/date stamp to scans of pre-1900 prints.

A date data type always has the components YEAR, MONTH and DAY in it. Do you store dates as a string or as date?

If it where me I would use a timestamp(tz) field and store the year/month dates as 2024-01-01 00:00:00 and the 'known' dates as 2024-01-01 12:00:00. Then you it would sort without resorting to string manipulation tricks.

How would it differentiate between 2024 X X and 2024 1 X? I'm categorizing family photos, everything from modern digital cameras with full time/date to scanned prints that are "probably pre-1900". I was first thinking store as string and replace any unknown with an X or underscore but I'd need a custom sort.


Add that requirement to the question text. As of now you have ...maybe you only know year and month. 2) For year only 2024-01-01 00:00:00 for month only 2024-01-01 01:00:00, for full date 2024-01-01 12:00:00.


Ok, I'm an idiot. I was thinking I had to add a character to replace the unknown values but if I just use 202401 for January 2024 and 20240101 for January 1st 2024 it sorts fine. If I don't know the day I certainly won't know the time. Anyway, thanks to all who looked at this and those who tried to help.
